# After Alexa speak output message and user voice command time can we play any music

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

After Alexa speak out message to user and after that user taking time to think about answer, during that time can we play music in background so that user consider Alexa skill is still live not ended?

User : "Invoked skill"
Alexa : "Welcome Message"
User : "Responded and skill flow start"
Alexa : " Ask question to the user which has long answer"

[ While user thinking Can we play any music so that user consider skill is still live and user take time to think during that time as user start responding music must stop.]

User : Thinking For Answer........

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and I do this for quiz skills.

However! While the "thinking" music is playing then the Alexa microphone is not open and so the user must use the wake word (Alexa, Ziggy, Computer / whatever) to give their answer.

So.

User : "Invoked skill"

Alexa : "Welcome Message"

User : "Responded and skill flow start"

Alexa : " Ask question to the user which has long answer" followed by "thinking" music

User : Thinking For Answer........

User: "Alexa, "

Alexa: Receives intent associated with  and processes it.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you share some resources how can i achieve this any documents or code snippet it will be helpful for me...

Comment: After Using audio in Alexa skill when Audio start and in between audio user responded and New intent triggers skill getting closed not triggering required intent?
While Audio is playing as user responded skill ends
Playing Audio file with SSML audio tag after speak output message.
speak_output = f" </speak> Please listen this audio clip: <audio 
                    src='{mp3_url}'/> </speak>" 
How can i keep session live when user responded in between audio and the intent i want to trigger should be executed..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you are correct - the music must stop for the microphone to open again.

For the music to stop, the customer must either interrupt it prefixing their response with the wake word, or wait for it to end before responding.

Like @allthepies, I use this for quizzes.  I keep the thinking music very short (10s max). Early in the skill session I explain that they can interrupt it with the wake word ("Alexa, my answer is ABC").  If they don't, and the music plays out, I re-prompt. I always end the re-prompt with "... if you need more time to think just say 'more time'".   My custom dialog handler just keeps eliciting the same slot until it resolves to something other than "more time".

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you share some code resources to implement this in python SDK in my Alexa skill.

Comment: If i did it with SSML Audio tag or need to use Audio player interface with .add_directive() method ? I am confused which one would work fine.